# Save array as an unordered list string

Tags: python

For example,

```
user_input = input("Create a list, separated by spaces: ")
user_input_array = user_input.split(" ")

output = """Here is your list, converted to bullet points:

""" + (for i in user_input_array: print(f" - {i}")) + """

End of list"""

print(output)
```

The above code returns `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` and points to the `(for` as the issue.

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `itertools.chain` and the string `.join()` method

```py
import itertools
value = "\n - ".join(itertools.chain(
    ["Here is your list, converted to bullet points:"],
    user_input_array
))
```

```py
>>> user_input_array
['a', 'b']
>>> print(value)
Here is your list, converted to bullet points:
 - a
 - b
```

Note `.join()` is a method on all strings, and is being called from `"\n - "` in this case!

Comment: @0x263A woops, fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a look at your code and try to make adjustments. I think the expected output gets confused when you tried to add the print output to a string.

```
user_input = input("Create a list, separated by spaces: ")
user_input_array = user_input.split(" ")

output = 'Here is your list, converted to bullet points:\n'
output += ''.join((f" - {i}\n" for i in user_input_array))
output += '\nEnd of list'

print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that's semi-readable (IMO):

```
user_input = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur"  # for testing
user_input_array = user_input.split(" ")

output = ("Here is your list, converted to bullet points:\n\n" +
          '\n'.join(f' + {word} +' for word in user_input_array) +
          "\nEnd of list")

print(output)
```